# how to revise link in header using code igniter template

Tags: php

I have a link in header that currently displays a list of stores assigned to this category. Categories are working properly but I will only assign one stores to each category created.

I am not sure how to get the category and sub-category to go directly to the store and not to showing the list of store(s). Basically I want to bypass the list view since there will only ever be one store per category or sub-category

Here is the code from that part of the header file.

```
          <li class="gnb"><a class="mn-stores" href="stores">Publications</a>
              <div class="menu-contain-gift">
                  <ul>
                      <?php
                      foreach ($mainPublications->result() as $row){
                          if ($row->pub_name != ''){
                              ?>
                              <li><a href="stores/?pubid=<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><?php echo $row->pub_name;?></a>
                              <?php if (in_array($row->id, $pub_root_id_arr)){?>
                                  <div class="submenu-contain">
                                      <ul>
                                          <?php
                                          foreach ($all_publication->result() as $row1){
                                              if ($row1->pub_name != '' && $row->id==$row1->rootID){ ?>
                                          <li style="position: relative;"><a href="stores/?pubid=<?php echo $row1->id; ?>"><?php echo $row1->pub_name;?></a>
                                              <?php }
                                          } ?>
                                      </ul>
                                  </div>
                              <?php } ?>
                              </li>
                          <?php }
                      } ?>
                  </ul>
```

Comment: Can you explain what is $mainPublications, $all_publication, rootID. What are categories here?

Comment: Thanks for the reply

The code is not necessarily wrong but we just want to skip the page where it show the listing of store in the category.
It is set up so that each category is assigned only one store (it will never be more than one) and the same for sub category. Currently when you click on category or sub category it show the page where it lists the store in the category then you have to click on the store to view. This all works but we want to bypass the list page and make it so when you click on the category it goes directly to the store assigned that category.

Comment: Here is the link. Click on publication in top menu of the site. you will see 2 categories and sub categories.

Comment: http://designtrades.org/stores/?pubid=3

Comment: Okay, I got the issue. Here you need to go to the store directly without listing the stores for the submenu publisher item click. You need to do this via the DB relations. Find the stores of that publisher and select first element (limit 1) then use that store id and make a link for that.

Comment: Do you mean I have to place code that would find each category ID or sub category ID and the store ID for each?

Comment: I was hoping it would be easier just to display without having to add it to code each time a new category or sub-category is added.

Comment: It currently works well except they have to do the extra click (on the list or row page) to get to the store.

Comment: stores/?pubid=<?php echo $row1->id; ?> Instead of this you would need to build a link for store with store_id. You should get that in your array while you fetch data from database. You can use table relations if these two (publications sub category and stores) come from two tables.